# HTML/CSS Nav Bar Not Responding Correctly

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, navbar

I'm somewhat new to more involved web design, if you can really call it that!
I seem to be having some issues with my navigation bar.
It seems to work on all my sections apart from one, the about section.

I've included all the CSS code since I think this is where the problem is.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.menu-toggler').on('click', function () {
        $(this).toggleClass('open');
        $('.top-nav').toggleClass('open');
    });

    $('.top-nav .nav-link').on('click', function () {
      $('.menu-toggler').removeClass('open');
      $('.top-nav').removeClass('open');
    });

    $('nav a[href*="#"]').not("#blog").on("click", function () {
      $("#js-menu").toggleClass('active');
   $("html, body").animate({
  scrollTop: $($(this).attr("href")).offset().top
   }, 500);
    });

    $("#up").on("click", function () {
      $("html, body").animate({
        scrollTop: 0
         }, 1000); 
    });
  });
```

```css
/*Start global*/
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

html{
    font-size: 15px;
    font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, 'Segoe UI', Roboto, Oxygen, Ubuntu, Cantarell, 'Open Sans', 'Helvetica Neue', sans-serif;
    color: #e9e9e9;
}

body{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: url("images/sitebg.jpg") no-repeat center fixed;
    background-size: cover;
    text-align: center;
}
section{
    padding: 6rem 0;
}
a{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #e9e9e9;
}

p{
    font-weight: 300;
    font-size: 1.8rem;
}

img{
    width: 100%;
}
/*End global*/

/*Start reusable*/
.container{
    width: 90%;
    max-width: 120rem;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: relative;
    padding: .3rem;
}

.section-heading{
    text-align: center;
    margin-bottom: 2.5rem;
}

.section-heading h1{
    font-size: 3.5rem;
    color: black;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight: 300;
    position: relative;
    margin-bottom: 1rem;
}

.section-heading h1::before,
.section-heading h1::after{
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -5rem;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.75);
}

.section-heading h1::before{
    width: 10rem;
    height: 3px;
    border-radius: 0.8rem;
    bottom: -4.5rem;
}


.section-heading h6{
    font-size: 1.6rem;
    font-weight: 300;
}

.has-margin-right{
    margin-right: 5rem;
}

/*End reusable*/

/*Start header*/
header{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

.top-nav{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    position: fixed;
    top: -100vh;
    z-index: 50;
    background-color: #16162d;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 100%;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 100%;
    transition: all 650ms cubic-bezier(1, 0, 0, 1);
}

.nav-list{
    list-style: none;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

li{
    margin: 0.2rem;
}
@font-face {
    font-family: 'The Historia Demo';
    src: url('/fonts/the_historia_demo-webfont.woff2') format('woff2'),
         url('fonts/the_historia_demo-webfont.woff') format('woff');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
  }
  
.nav-link{
font-family:"The Historia Demo", sans-serif;
    font-size: 5rem;
    padding: 1rem;
}

.nav-link:hover,
.nav-link:focus{
    background: linear-gradient(to top, #ffe838, #fd57bf );
    -webkit-background-clip: text;
    -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
}

.top-nav.open{
    top: 0;
    border-radius: initial;
}

.menu-toggler{
    position: absolute;
    top: 5rem;
    right: 5rem;
    width: 5rem;
    height: 4rem;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: space-between;
    cursor: pointer;
    z-index: 1500;
    transition: transform 650ms ease-out;
}

.menu-toggler.open{
    transform: rotate(-45deg);
}

.bar{
    background: linear-gradient(to right, #ffe838, #fd57bf);
    width: 100%;
    height: 4px;
    border-radius: .8rem;
}

.bar.half{
    width: 50%;
}

.bar.start{
    transform-origin: right;
    transition: transform 650ms cubic-bezier(0.54, -0.81, 0.057, 0.57);
}

.open .bar.start{
    transform: rotate(-450deg) translateX(.8rem);
}

.bar.end{
    align-self: flex-end;
    transform-origin: left;
    transition: transform 650ms cubic-bezier(0.54, -0.81, 0.057, 0.57);
}

.open .bar.end{
    transform: rotate(-450deg) translateX(-.8rem);
}

.landing-text{
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    z-index: 1;
}

.landing-text h1{
    font-size: 15rem;
    font-weight: 500;
    font-family: "The Historia Demo", sans-serif;
    background: linear-gradient(to top, #ffe838 30%, #fd57bf );
    -webkit-background-clip: text;
    -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
    padding: 1rem;
    user-select: none;
    line-height: 1.1;
}

.landing-text h6{
    font-size: 2rem;
    font-weight: 300;
    margin-bottom: 0.4rem;
}

.landingbtn {
    margin: 1rem auto;
    background-color:#16162d;
    height: 3rem;
    width: 15rem;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: 0.2s ease-in;
    border-radius: 1rem;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    text-transform: capitalize;
    opacity: 0.5;
  
}
  
.landingbtn p {
    font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, 'Segoe UI', Roboto, Oxygen, Ubuntu, Cantarell, 'Open Sans', 'Helvetica Neue', sans-serif;
    font-size: 2rem;
}
  
.landingbtn:hover {
    transform: scale(1.05);
    background-color: #221e3f;
}
/*End header*/

/*Start about*/
.about .container{
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    margin-top: 60rem;
}

.about-heading{
    text-align: center;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    line-height: 0;
    margin-bottom: 6rem;
}

.about-heading h1{
    font-size: 10rem;
    opacity: .3;
}


.about-heading h6{
    font-size: 2rem;
    font-weight: 300;
}

.profile-img{
    flex: 1;
    margin-right: 5rem;
}

.about-details{
    flex: 1;
}

.social-media{
    margin-top: 5rem;
}

.social-media i{
    font-size: 5rem;
    transition: color 650ms;
    padding: 1rem;
}

.fa-linkedin:hover{
    color: #0e76a8;
}

.fa-github:hover{
    color: #211F1F;
}

.fa-soundcloud:hover{
    color: #ff7700;
}

/*End about*/

/*Start services*/
.my-skills{
    margin-top: 3.5rem;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(25rem, 1fr));
    grid-gap: 2.5rem;
    text-align: center;

}
```

```html
<body>
    <header>
        <div class="menu-toggler">
            <div class="bar half start"></div>
            <div class="bar"></div>
            <div class="bar half end"></div>
        </div>   
        <nav class="top-nav">
            <ul class="nav-list">
                <li>
                    <a href="index.html" class ="nav-link">Home</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#about" class="nav-link">About</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#services" class ="nav-link">Services</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#portfolio" class ="nav-link">Portfolio</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#experience" class ="nav-link">Experience</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="contact" class ="nav-link">Contact</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </nav>


        <div class="landing-text">
            <h1>Karanvir S. Ghatt</h1>
            
            <h6>Full Stack Developer | Scientist | Artist </h6>
            <h6> I Am
                <a href="" class="typewrite" data-period="2000" data-type='[ " Creative.", " Driven.", " Analytical." ]'>
                  <span class="wrap"></span>
                </a>
              </h6>

              <a class="landingbtn" href="#portfolio">
                <p> See my work </p>
            </a>
        </div>
    </header>

    <section id="about" class="about">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="prolife-img" data-aos="fade-right" data-aos-delay="200">
                <img src="images/profile(1).png" alt="avatar image">
            </div>
            <div class="about-details" data-aos="fade-left" data-aos-delay="400">
                <div class="about-heading">
                    <h1>About</h1>
                </div>
                <p>
                    A confident individual offering skills in a range of areas, 
                    from anlytical and formulation chemistry to, web development, 
                    backend, hospitality and sales. 

                    Self-taught full stack developer, offering skills in web-design, 
                    python, data science and analysis. 
                </p>
                <div class="social-media">
                    <ul class="nav-list">
                        <li>
                            <a href="#" class="icon-link">
                                <i class="fab fa-linkedin"></i>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#" class="icon-link">
                                <i class="fab fa-github"></i>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#" class="icon-link">
                                <i class="fab fa-soundcloud"></i>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>

    <section class="services" id="services">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="section-heading">
                <h1 data-aos="zoom-in" data-aos-delay="100">Services</h1>
                <h6 data-aos="zoom-in" data-aos-delay="100">What I Can Do For You</h6>
            </div>
            <div class="my-skills">
                <div class="skill" data-aos="fade-left" data-aos-delay="300">
                    <div class="icon-container">
                        <i class="fas fa-code"></i>
                    </div>
                    <h1>Design & Development</h1>
                    <p>
                        Good web design is more thanjust pixelated information. 
                        It should be seamless, it should be invisible. 
                        In my hands, every project is bespoke and tailored to your specific needs and requirements.
                        In a few short months I have developed and deployed a number of websites, find our more in my portfolio.
                        
                    </p>
                </div>
                <div class="skill" data-aos="fade-in" data-aos-delay="150">
                    <div class="icon-container">
                        <i class="fa fa-cogs"></i>
                    </div>
                    <h1>Design & Deployment</h1>
                    <p>
                        Over the last few months I have devloped my python skills, developing a number of applications,
                        and sucessfully depolying a few. I am drawn to data analysis and visulation, data can truly be beautiful. 
                        Although not an expert, far from it, I am working everyday to expand my skillset.
                        What I have developed so far, in a short period of time, can show what I can do.
                    </p>
                </div>
                <div class="skill" data-aos="fade-right" data-aos-delay="300">
                    <div class="icon-container">  
                        <i class="fa fa-dashboard"></i>
                    </div>
                    <h1>Versitility</h1>
                    <p>
                        I take pride in having a versitile skill-set, from sales,  to business, to programming, to life sciences, to music and creative design. 
                        Those 'soft-skils', and my exposiure to a range of feilds and industries, means that I'm sure there's some way I can be of service.
                        These are more words, included to make this look right. 
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>


    <section class="portfolio" id="portfolio">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="section-heading" data-aos="zoom-in" data-aos-delay="100">
                <h1 data-aos="fade-right" data-aos-delay="150">Portfolio</h1>
                <h6 data-aos="fade-left" data-aos-delay="150">Veiw Recent Projects</h6>
            </div>
            </div>

            <div class="row" data-aos="fade-down" data-aos-delay="200"> 

                <!-- Portfolio Item 1 | AB Removals -->
                <div class="column">
                    <div class="portfolio-container">
                        <div class="item" id="1">
                            <img src="/images/abremovals.png" style="width:100%"  alt="">
                            <div class="text">
                                <h3>PROJECT 1</h4>
                                    <p>Short Description</p>
                                </div>
                                <div class="button">Learn More</div>
                            </div>
                    </div>

                    <!-- Portfolio Item 2 | Resume -->
                    <div class="portfolio-container">
                        <div class="item" id="2">
                            <img src="/images/resume.png" style="width:100%" alt="">
                            <div class="text">
                                <h3>PROJECT 2</h4>
                                    <p>Short Description</p>
                                </div>
                                <div class="button">Learn More</div>
                            </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

            
            <!-- Portfolio Item 3 | Resume -->
            <div class="column">
                <div class="portfolio-container">
                    <div class="item" id="3">
                        <img src="/images/portfolio.png" style="width:100%" alt="">
                        <div class="text">
                            <h3>PROJECT 3</h4>
                                <p>Short Description</p>
                            </div>
                            <div class="button">Learn More</div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <!-- Portfolio Item 4 | Data Projects -->
                    <div class="portfolio-container">
                        <div class="item" id="4">
                            <img src="/images/covid.png" style="width:100%" alt="">
                            <div class="text">
                                <h3>PROJECT 4</h4>
                                    <p>Short Description</p>
                                </div>
                                <div class="button">Learn More</div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
            </div>

            

            <!-- Portfolio Item 5 | Colour Detection -->
            <div class="column">
                <div class="portfolio-container">
                    <div class="item" id="5">
                        <img src="/images/testimage.gif" style="width:100%" alt="">
                        <div class="text">
                            <h3>PROJECT 5</h4>
                                <p>Short Description</p>
                            </div>
                            <div class="button">Learn More</div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <!-- Portfolio Item 6 | Face Detection -->
                    <div class="portfolio-container">
                    <div class="item" id="6">
                        <img src="/images/testgiftwo.gif" alt="">
                        <div class="text">
                            <h3>PROJECT 6</h4>
                                <p>Short Description</p>
                            </div>
                            <div class="button">Learn More</div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
            </div>

                        <!-- Portfolio Item 7 | Colour Detection -->
                        <div class="column">
                            <div class="portfolio-container">
                                <div class="item" id="7">
                                    <img src="/images/testimage.gif" style="width:100%" alt="">
                                    <div class="text">
                                        <h3>PROJECT 7</h4>
                                            <p>Short Description</p>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="button">Learn More</div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <!-- Portfolio Item 8 | Colour Detection -->
                                <div class="portfolio-container">
                                <div class="item" id="8">
                                    <img src="/images/testimage.gif" style="width:100%" alt="">
                                    <div class="text">
                                        <h3>PROJECT 8</h4>
                                            <p>Short Description</p>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="button">Learn More</div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                        </div>
            

            <!-- Modal -->
            <div id="preview" class="modal">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <span class="close">&times;</span>
                    <div id="details">
                        <h3 id="title"></h3>
                        <p id="info">SOME TEXT</p>
                        <div class="button" id="live">View</div>
                        <i class="fab fa-github-square" id="github"></i>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- Item End -->            

            

    </section>

    <section class="experience" id="experience">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="section-heading">
                <h1 data-aos="fade-left" data-aos-delay="150">Work Experience</h1>
                <h6 data-aos="fade-right" data-aos-delay="150">Previous Roles</h6>
            </div>
            <div class="timeline" data-aos="fade-down" data-aos-delay="200">
                <ul>
                    <li class="date" data-date="Oct 2018 - Dec 2019">
                        <h1>Mettler Toledo | Sales Coordinator</h1>
                        <p>
                            The key aim of this role was to sell or introduce new corporate products or services to
                            established clients, along with prospecting for new business, the generation and qualification of sales leads.

                            Management of project execution actions and overall coordination between Internal and Outside Sales departments,
                            along with key stakeholders both inside, and beyond the business.
                        </p>
                    </li>
                    <li class="date" data-date="Mar 2018 - Jan 2019">
                        <h1>Vape.ABox | Flavourist - Lead Chemist</h1>
                        <p>
                            Set up and maintenance of the analytical laboratory on site, along with product procurement.
                            Demonstration of creation leadership potential through commercial projects & their execution.
                            Creation of new flavors and re-formulation of current flavours, with regards to specific technologies and delivery systems.
                        </p>
                    </li>
                    <li class="date" data-date="Mar 2018 - Jan 2019">
                        <h1>3M | QC Inhilations Chemist</h1>
                        <p>
                            Testing of pharmaceutical products for batch release, stability and complaints in line with departmental
                            and site procedures across a number of departments.
                            Completion of work and documentation to standards of compliance designated by external regulatory 
                            bodies and internal Company procedures.

                        </p>
                    </li>
                    <h2>Further information regarding my work experience can be found in my Resume</h2>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>

    <section class="contact" id="contact">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="section-heading">
                <h1 data-aos="fade-right" data-aos-delay="150">Contact</h1>
                <h6 data-aos="fade-left" data-aos-delay="150">Contact Me</h6>
            </div>
            <form actions="" data-aos="fade-up" data-aos-delay="200">
                <label for="name">Name:</label>
                <input type="text" id="name" name="name" placeholder="Enter Your Name..." required>

                <label for="name">Email:</label>
                <input type="email" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Enter Your E-mail..." required>

                <label for="number">Contact Number:</label>
                <input type="number" id="number" name="number" placeholder="Enter Your Contact Number...">
                
                <label for="message">Message:</label>
                <textarea name="subject" id="subject" cols="10" rows="10" placeholder="Enter Your Messgage..."></textarea>
                <input type="submit" value="Subit">


            </form>
        </div>
    </section>

    <footer class="copyright">
        <div class="up" id="up">
                    <i class="fas fa fa-chevron-up"></i>
        </div>
        <p>&copy; 2020 Karanvir S. Ghattoraya</p>
    </footer>


    
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/aos@next/dist/aos.js"></script>
    <script src="main.js"></script>





</body>
</html>
```

Any insight would be greatly appreciated!!

Comment: What exactly is the issue? What should it do that it's not doing?

Comment: @IslamElshobokshy The link to the about section, from the nav-bar, dose not seem to be working, not too sure why

Comment: Please avoid posting profanity, as it is noticed and could subject you to flags and moderator action.

Comment: Correct me if i'm wrong but, I'm not using any profane language? @Machavity

Comment: Please see revision 3. Your code contained a very strong vulgarity which all subsequent answers copied https://stackoverflow.com/posts/62445447/revisions

Comment: @Machavity I still can't seem to see it, but I apologize. I will make sure to monitor my language next time. Thanks for the revision to make it presentable.

Answer (score 1):

> You have the `.container` of about section with `margin-top: 60rem;`
>   so technically **the anchor point is working** but its position is at the
>   top of the document :(

To avoid this, you can change the `position:absolute` of the `.landing-text` to default value and the about section it will go down `.landing-text` with no `margin-top` to simulate its position. I hope this can help you.

**Here is the code:** 
*(Run code snippet with full page to see the solution)*

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.menu-toggler').on('click', function () {
        $(this).toggleClass('open');
        $('.top-nav').toggleClass('open');
    });

    $('.top-nav .nav-link').on('click', function () {
      $('.menu-toggler').removeClass('open');
      $('.top-nav').removeClass('open');
    });

    $('nav a[href*="#"]').not("#blog").on("click", function () {
      $("#js-menu").toggleClass('active');
   $("html, body").animate({
  scrollTop: $($(this).attr("href")).offset().top
   }, 500);
    });

    $("#up").on("click", function () {
      $("html, body").animate({
        scrollTop: 0
         }, 1000); 
    });
  });
```

```css
/*Start global*/
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

html{
    font-size: 15px;
    font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, 'Segoe UI', Roboto, Oxygen, Ubuntu, Cantarell, 'Open Sans', 'Helvetica Neue', sans-serif;
    color: #e9e9e9;
}

body{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: url("images/sitebg.jpg") no-repeat center fixed;
    background-size: cover;
    text-align: center;
}
section{
    padding: 6rem 0;
}
a{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #e9e9e9;
}

p{
    font-weight: 300;
    font-size: 1.8rem;
}

img{
    width: 100%;
}
/*End global*/

/*Start reusable*/
.container{
    width: 90%;
    max-width: 120rem;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: relative;
    padding: .3rem;
}

.section-heading{
    text-align: center;
    margin-bottom: 2.5rem;
}

.section-heading h1{
    font-size: 3.5rem;
    color: black;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight: 300;
    position: relative;
    margin-bottom: 1rem;
}

.section-heading h1::before,
.section-heading h1::after{
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -5rem;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.75);
}

.section-heading h1::before{
    width: 10rem;
    height: 3px;
    border-radius: 0.8rem;
    bottom: -4.5rem;
}


.section-heading h6{
    font-size: 1.6rem;
    font-weight: 300;
}

.has-margin-right{
    margin-right: 5rem;
}

/*End reusable*/

/*Start header*/
header{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

.top-nav{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    position: fixed;
    top: -100vh;
    z-index: 50;
    background-color: #16162d;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 100%;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 100%;
    transition: all 650ms cubic-bezier(1, 0, 0, 1);
}

.nav-list{
    list-style: none;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

li{
    margin: 0.2rem;
}
@font-face {
    font-family: 'The Historia Demo';
    src: url('/fonts/the_historia_demo-webfont.woff2') format('woff2'),
         url('fonts/the_historia_demo-webfont.woff') format('woff');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
  }
  
.nav-link{
font-family:"The Historia Demo", sans-serif;
    font-size: 5rem;
    padding: 1rem;
}

.nav-link:hover,
.nav-link:focus{
    background: linear-gradient(to top, #ffe838, #fd57bf );
    -webkit-background-clip: text;
    -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
}

.top-nav.open{
    top: 0;
    border-radius: initial;
}

.menu-toggler{
    position: absolute;
    top: 5rem;
    right: 5rem;
    width: 5rem;
    height: 4rem;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: space-between;
    cursor: pointer;
    z-index: 1500;
    transition: transform 650ms ease-out;
}

.menu-toggler.open{
    transform: rotate(-45deg);
}

.bar{
    background: linear-gradient(to right, #ffe838, #fd57bf);
    width: 100%;
    height: 4px;
    border-radius: .8rem;
}

.bar.half{
    width: 50%;
}

.bar.start{
    transform-origin: right;
    transition: transform 650ms cubic-bezier(0.54, -0.81, 0.057, 0.57);
}

.open .bar.start{
    transform: rotate(-450deg) translateX(.8rem);
}

.bar.end{
    align-self: flex-end;
    transform-origin: left;
    transition: transform 650ms cubic-bezier(0.54, -0.81, 0.057, 0.57);
}

.open .bar.end{
    transform: rotate(-450deg) translateX(-.8rem);
}

.landing-text{
    width: 100%;
}

.landing-text h1{
    font-size: 15rem;
    font-weight: 500;
    font-family: "The Historia Demo", sans-serif;
    background: linear-gradient(to top, #ffe838 30%, #fd57bf );
    -webkit-background-clip: text;
    -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
    padding: 1rem;
    user-select: none;
    line-height: 1.1;
}

.landing-text h6{
    font-size: 2rem;
    font-weight: 300;
    margin-bottom: 0.4rem;
}

.landingbtn {
    margin: 1rem auto;
    background-color:#16162d;
    height: 3rem;
    width: 15rem;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: 0.2s ease-in;
    border-radius: 1rem;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    text-transform: capitalize;
    opacity: 0.5;
  
}
  
.landingbtn p {
    font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, 'Segoe UI', Roboto, Oxygen, Ubuntu, Cantarell, 'Open Sans', 'Helvetica Neue', sans-serif;
    font-size: 2rem;
}
  
.landingbtn:hover {
    transform: scale(1.05);
    background-color: #221e3f;
}
/*End header*/

/*Start about*/
.about .container{
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}

.about-heading{
    text-align: center;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    line-height: 0;
    margin-bottom: 6rem;
}

.about-heading h1{
    font-size: 10rem;
    opacity: .3;
}


.about-heading h6{
    font-size: 2rem;
    font-weight: 300;
}

.profile-img{
    flex: 1;
    margin-right: 5rem;
}

.about-details{
    flex: 1;
}

.social-media{
    margin-top: 5rem;
}

.social-media i{
    font-size: 5rem;
    transition: color 650ms;
    padding: 1rem;
}

.fa-linkedin:hover{
    color: #0e76a8;
}

.fa-github:hover{
    color: #211F1F;
}

.fa-soundcloud:hover{
    color: #ff7700;
}

/*End about*/

/*Start services*/
.my-skills{
    margin-top: 3.5rem;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(25rem, 1fr));
    grid-gap: 2.5rem;
    text-align: center;

}
```

```html
<body>
    <header>
        <div class="menu-toggler">
            <div class="bar half start"></div>
            <div class="bar"></div>
            <div class="bar half end"></div>
        </div>   
        <nav class="top-nav">
            <ul class="nav-list">
                <li>
                    <a href="index.html" class ="nav-link">Home</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#about" class="nav-link">About</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#services" class ="nav-link">Services</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#portfolio" class ="nav-link">Portfolio</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#experience" class ="nav-link">Experience</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="contact" class ="nav-link">Contact</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </header>
<div class="landing-text">
            <h1>Karanvir S. Ghatt</h1>
            
            <h6>Full Stack Developer | Scientist | Artist </h6>
            <h6> I Am
                <a href="" class="typewrite" data-period="2000" data-type='[ " Creative.", " Driven.", " Analytical." ]'>
                  <span class="wrap"></span>
                </a>
              </h6>

              <a class="landingbtn" href="#portfolio">
                <p> See my work </p>
            </a>
        </div>
    <section id="about" class="about">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="prolife-img" data-aos="fade-right" data-aos-delay="200">
                <img src="images/profile(1).png" alt="avatar image">
            </div>
            <div class="about-details" data-aos="fade-left" data-aos-delay="400">
                <div class="about-heading">
                    <h1>About</h1>
                </div>
                <p>
                    A confident individual offering skills in a range of areas, 
                    from anlytical and formulation chemistry to, web development, 
                    backend, hospitality and sales. 

                    Self-taught full stack developer, offering skills in web-design, 
                    python, data science and analysis. 
                </p>
                <div class="social-media">
                    <ul class="nav-list">
                        <li>
                            <a href="#" class="icon-link">
                                <i class="fab fa-linkedin"></i>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#" class="icon-link">
                                <i class="fab fa-github"></i>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#" class="icon-link">
                                <i class="fab fa-soundcloud"></i>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>

    <section class="services" id="services">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="section-heading">
                <h1 data-aos="zoom-in" data-aos-delay="100">Services</h1>
                <h6 data-aos="zoom-in" data-aos-delay="100">What I Can Do For You</h6>
            </div>
            <div class="my-skills">
                <div class="skill" data-aos="fade-left" data-aos-delay="300">
                    <div class="icon-container">
                        <i class="fas fa-code"></i>
                    </div>
                    <h1>Design & Development</h1>
                    <p>
                        Good web design is more thanjust pixelated information. 
                        It should be seamless, it should be invisible. 
                        In my hands, every project is bespoke and tailored to your specific needs and requirements.
                        In a few short months I have developed and deployed a number of websites, find our more in my portfolio.
                        
                    </p>
                </div>
                <div class="skill" data-aos="fade-in" data-aos-delay="150">
                    <div class="icon-container">
                        <i class="fa fa-cogs"></i>
                    </div>
                    <h1>Design & Deployment</h1>
                    <p>
                        Over the last few months I have devloped my python skills, developing a number of applications,
                        and sucessfully depolying a few. I am drawn to data analysis and visulation, data can truly be beautiful. 
                        Although not an expert, far from it, I am working everyday to expand my skillset.
                        What I have developed so far, in a short period of time, can show what I can do.
                    </p>
                </div>
                <div class="skill" data-aos="fade-right" data-aos-delay="300">
                    <div class="icon-container">  
                        <i class="fa fa-dashboard"></i>
                    </div>
                    <h1>Versitility</h1>
                    <p>
                        I take pride in having a versitile skill-set, from sales,  to business, to programming, to life sciences, to music and creative design. 
                        Those 'soft-skils', and my exposiure to a range of feilds and industries, means that I'm sure there's some way I can be of service.
                        These are more words, included to make this look right. 
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>


    <section class="portfolio" id="portfolio">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="section-heading" data-aos="zoom-in" data-aos-delay="100">
                <h1 data-aos="fade-right" data-aos-delay="150">Portfolio</h1>
                <h6 data-aos="fade-left" data-aos-delay="150">Veiw Recent Projects</h6>
            </div>
            </div>

            <div class="row" data-aos="fade-down" data-aos-delay="200"> 

                <!-- Portfolio Item 1 | AB Removals -->
                <div class="column">
                    <div class="portfolio-container">
                        <div class="item" id="1">
                            <img src="/images/abremovals.png" style="width:100%"  alt="">
                            <div class="text">
                                <h3>PROJECT 1</h4>
                                    <p>Short Description</p>
                                </div>
                                <div class="button">Learn More</div>
                            </div>
                    </div>

                    <!-- Portfolio Item 2 | Resume -->
                    <div class="portfolio-container">
                        <div class="item" id="2">
                            <img src="/images/resume.png" style="width:100%" alt="">
                            <div class="text">
                                <h3>PROJECT 2</h4>
                                    <p>Short Description</p>
                                </div>
                                <div class="button">Learn More</div>
                            </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

            
            <!-- Portfolio Item 3 | Resume -->
            <div class="column">
                <div class="portfolio-container">
                    <div class="item" id="3">
                        <img src="/images/portfolio.png" style="width:100%" alt="">
                        <div class="text">
                            <h3>PROJECT 3</h4>
                                <p>Short Description</p>
                            </div>
                            <div class="button">Learn More</div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <!-- Portfolio Item 4 | Data Projects -->
                    <div class="portfolio-container">
                        <div class="item" id="4">
                            <img src="/images/covid.png" style="width:100%" alt="">
                            <div class="text">
                                <h3>PROJECT 4</h4>
                                    <p>Short Description</p>
                                </div>
                                <div class="button">Learn More</div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
            </div>

            

            <!-- Portfolio Item 5 | Colour Detection -->
            <div class="column">
                <div class="portfolio-container">
                    <div class="item" id="5">
                        <img src="/images/testimage.gif" style="width:100%" alt="">
                        <div class="text">
                            <h3>PROJECT 5</h4>
                                <p>Short Description</p>
                            </div>
                            <div class="button">Learn More</div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <!-- Portfolio Item 6 | Face Detection -->
                    <div class="portfolio-container">
                    <div class="item" id="6">
                        <img src="/images/testgiftwo.gif" alt="">
                        <div class="text">
                            <h3>PROJECT 6</h4>
                                <p>Short Description</p>
                            </div>
                            <div class="button">Learn More</div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
            </div>

                        <!-- Portfolio Item 7 | Colour Detection -->
                        <div class="column">
                            <div class="portfolio-container">
                                <div class="item" id="7">
                                    <img src="/images/testimage.gif" style="width:100%" alt="">
                                    <div class="text">
                                        <h3>PROJECT 7</h4>
                                            <p>Short Description</p>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="button">Learn More</div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <!-- Portfolio Item 8 | Colour Detection -->
                                <div class="portfolio-container">
                                <div class="item" id="8">
                                    <img src="/images/testimage.gif" style="width:100%" alt="">
                                    <div class="text">
                                        <h3>PROJECT 8</h4>
                                            <p>Short Description</p>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="button">Learn More</div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                        </div>
            

            <!-- Modal -->
            <div id="preview" class="modal">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <span class="close">&times;</span>
                    <div id="details">
                        <h3 id="title"></h3>
                        <p id="info">SOME TEXT</p>
                        <div class="button" id="live">View</div>
                        <i class="fab fa-github-square" id="github"></i>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- Item End -->            

            

    </section>

    <section class="experience" id="experience">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="section-heading">
                <h1 data-aos="fade-left" data-aos-delay="150">Work Experience</h1>
                <h6 data-aos="fade-right" data-aos-delay="150">Previous Roles</h6>
            </div>
            <div class="timeline" data-aos="fade-down" data-aos-delay="200">
                <ul>
                    <li class="date" data-date="Oct 2018 - Dec 2019">
                        <h1>Mettler Toledo | Sales Coordinator</h1>
                        <p>
                            The key aim of this role was to sell or introduce new corporate products or services to
                            established clients, along with prospecting for new business, the generation and qualification of sales leads.

                            Management of project execution actions and overall coordination between Internal and Outside Sales departments,
                            along with key stakeholders both inside, and beyond the business.
                        </p>
                    </li>
                    <li class="date" data-date="Mar 2018 - Jan 2019">
                        <h1>Vape.ABox | Flavourist - Lead Chemist</h1>
                        <p>
                            Set up and maintenance of the analytical laboratory on site, along with product procurement.
                            Demonstration of creation leadership potential through commercial projects & their execution.
                            Creation of new flavors and re-formulation of current flavours, with regards to specific technologies and delivery systems.
                        </p>
                    </li>
                    <li class="date" data-date="Mar 2018 - Jan 2019">
                        <h1>3M | QC Inhilations Chemist</h1>
                        <p>
                            Testing of pharmaceutical products for batch release, stability and complaints in line with departmental
                            and site procedures across a number of departments.
                            Completion of work and documentation to standards of compliance designated by external regulatory 
                            bodies and internal Company procedures.

                        </p>
                    </li>
                    <h2>Further information regarding my work experience can be found in my Resume</h2>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>

    <section class="contact" id="contact">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="section-heading">
                <h1 data-aos="fade-right" data-aos-delay="150">Contact</h1>
                <h6 data-aos="fade-left" data-aos-delay="150">Contact Me</h6>
            </div>
            <form actions="" data-aos="fade-up" data-aos-delay="200">
                <label for="name">Name:</label>
                <input type="text" id="name" name="name" placeholder="Enter Your Name..." required>

                <label for="name">Email:</label>
                <input type="email" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Enter Your E-mail..." required>

                <label for="number">Contact Number:</label>
                <input type="number" id="number" name="number" placeholder="Enter Your Contact Number...">
                
                <label for="message">Message:</label>
                <textarea name="subject" id="subject" cols="10" rows="10" placeholder="Enter Your Messgage..."></textarea>
                <input type="submit" value="Subit">


            </form>
        </div>
    </section>

    <footer class="copyright">
        <div class="up" id="up">
                    <i class="fas fa fa-chevron-up"></i>
        </div>
        <p>&copy; 2020 Karanvir S. Ghattoraya</p>
    </footer>


    
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/aos@next/dist/aos.js"></script>
    <script src="main.js"></script>





</body>
</html>
```

Comment: thanks for your help! This dose seem to make the nav-bar work, however now the about section text is overlapping my landing text, even after moving the header to under the </nav>. and it looks like my landing text is covering up the burger menu.

 I managed to get somewhat of a work around, by adding a margin top and a margin bottom to the .landing-text, but it's sill not quite right - if I resize the display the text moves around/not really responsive.

Thanks again for you help, and any further insight is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

```js
    
    $(document).ready(function () {
    $('.menu-toggler').on('click', function () {
        $(this).toggleClass('open');
        $('.top-nav').toggleClass('open');
    });

    $('.top-nav .nav-link').on('click', function () {
      $('.menu-toggler').removeClass('open');
      $('.top-nav').removeClass('open');
    });

    $('nav a[href*="#"]').not("#blog").on("click", function () {
      $("#js-menu").toggleClass('active');
   $("html, body").animate({
  scrollTop: $($(this).attr("href")).offset().top
   }, 500);
    });

    $("#up").on("click", function () {
      $("html, body").animate({
        scrollTop: 0
         }, 1000); 
    });
  });
```

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

html {
    font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, 'Segoe UI', Roboto, Oxygen, Ubuntu, Cantarell, 'Open Sans', 'Helvetica Neue';
    color: #e9e9e9;
}

body {
    text-align: center;
}

section {
    padding: 6rem 0;
}

a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #e9e9e9;
}

p {
    font-weight: 300;
    font-size: 1.8rem;
}

img {
    width: 100%;
}


/*End global*/


/*Start reusable*/

.container {
    width: 90%;
    max-width: 120rem;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: relative;
    padding: .3rem;
}

.section-heading {
    text-align: center;
    margin-bottom: 2.5rem;
}

.section-heading h1 {
    font-size: 3.5rem;
    color: black;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight: 300;
    position: relative;
    margin-bottom: 1rem;
}

.section-heading h1::before,
.section-heading h1::after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -5rem;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.75);
}

.section-heading h1::before {
    width: 10rem;
    height: 3px;
    border-radius: 0.8rem;
    bottom: -4.5rem;
}

.section-heading h6 {
    font-size: 1.6rem;
    font-weight: 300;
}

.has-margin-right {
    margin-right: 5rem;
}


/*End reusable*/


/*Start header*/

header {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

.top-nav {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    position: fixed;
    top: -100vh;
    z-index: 50;
    background-color: #16162d;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 100%;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 100%;
    transition: all 650ms cubic-bezier(1, 0, 0, 1);
}

.nav-list {
    list-style: none;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

li {
    margin: 0.2rem;
}

@font-face {
    font-family: 'The Historia Demo';
    src: url('/fonts/the_historia_demo-webfont.woff2') format('woff2'), url('fonts/the_historia_demo-webfont.woff') format('woff');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}

.nav-link {
    font-family: "The Historia Demo", sans-serif;
    font-size: 2rem;
    padding: 1rem;
}

.nav-link:hover,
.nav-link:focus {
    background: linear-gradient(to top, #ffe838, #fd57bf);
    -webkit-background-clip: text;
    -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
}

.top-nav.open {
    top: 0;
    border-radius: initial;
}

.menu-toggler {
    position: absolute;
    top: 5rem;
    right: 5rem;
    width: 5rem;
    height: 4rem;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: space-between;
    cursor: pointer;
    z-index: 1500;
    transition: transform 650ms ease-out;
}

.menu-toggler.open {
    transform: rotate(-45deg);
}

.bar {
    background: linear-gradient(to right, #ffe838, #fd57bf);
    width: 100%;
    height: 4px;
    border-radius: .8rem;
}

.bar.half {
    width: 50%;
}

.bar.start {
    transform-origin: right;
    transition: transform 650ms cubic-bezier(0.54, -0.81, 0.057, 0.57);
}

.open .bar.start {
    transform: rotate(-450deg) translateX(.8rem);
}

.bar.end {
    align-self: flex-end;
    transform-origin: left;
    transition: transform 650ms cubic-bezier(0.54, -0.81, 0.057, 0.57);
}

.open .bar.end {
    transform: rotate(-450deg) translateX(-.8rem);
}

.landing-text {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    z-index: 1;
}

.landing-text h1 {
    font-size: 5rem;
    font-weight: 500;
    font-family: "The Historia Demo", sans-serif;
    background: linear-gradient(to top, #ffe838 30%, #fd57bf);
    -webkit-background-clip: text;
    -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
    padding: 1rem;
    user-select: none;
    line-height: 1.1;
}

.landing-text h6 {
    font-size: 1.5rem;
    font-weight: 300;
    margin-bottom: 0.4rem;
}

.landingbtn {
    margin: 1rem auto;
    background-color: #16162d;
    height: 3rem;
    width: 15rem;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: 0.2s ease-in;
    border-radius: 1rem;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    text-transform: capitalize;
    opacity: 0.5;
}

.landingbtn p {
    font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, 'Segoe UI', Roboto, Oxygen, Ubuntu, Cantarell, 'Open Sans', 'Helvetica Neue';
    font-size: 2rem;
}

.landingbtn:hover {
    transform: scale(1.05);
    background-color: #221e3f;
}


/*End header*/


/*Start about*/

.about .container {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    margin-top: 60rem;
}

.about-heading {
    text-align: center;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    line-height: 0;
    margin-bottom: 6rem;
}

.about-heading h1 {
    font-size: 10rem;
    opacity: .3;
}

.about-heading h6 {
    font-size: 2rem;
    font-weight: 300;
}

.profile-img {
    flex: 1;
    margin-right: 5rem;
}

.about-details {
    flex: 1;
}

.social-media {
    margin-top: 5rem;
}

.social-media i {
    font-size: 5rem;
    transition: color 650ms;
    padding: 1rem;
}

.fa-linkedin:hover {
    color: #0e76a8;
}

.fa-github:hover {
    color: #211F1F;
}

.fa-soundcloud:hover {
    color: #ff7700;
}


/*End about*/


/*Start services*/

.my-skills {
    margin-top: 3.5rem;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(25rem, 1fr));
    grid-gap: 2.5rem;
    text-align: center;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
   .nav-list {
        display: block;
   }

   .nav-list{
       margin-top: 48%;
           margin-left: -7%;
   }

   .nav-list li{
        margin-top: 10px;
   }
   .menu-toggler {    width: 4rem;
    height: 3rem;right: 4rem;}

    .landing-text h1 {
    font-size: 3rem; margin-bottom: 20px;}

    .landingbtn {    width: 10rem;}

    .landingbtn p{font-size: 24px;}

    .about-details{margin-left: -27%;}

    .about-heading h1 {
    font-size: 6rem;}

}
```

```html
<body>
    <header>
        <div class="menu-toggler">
            <div class="bar half start"></div>
            <div class="bar"></div>
            <div class="bar half end"></div>
        </div>   
        <nav class="top-nav">
            <ul class="nav-list">
                <li>
                    <a href="index.html" class ="nav-link">Home</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#about" class="nav-link">About</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#services" class ="nav-link">Services</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#portfolio" class ="nav-link">Portfolio</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#experience" class ="nav-link">Experience</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="contact" class ="nav-link">Contact</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </nav>


        <div class="landing-text">
            <h1>Karanvir S. Ghatt</h1>
            
            <h6>Full Stack Developer | Scientist | Artist </h6>
            <h6> I Am
                <a href="" class="typewrite" data-period="2000" data-type='[ " Creative.", " Driven.", " Analytical." ]'>
                  <span class="wrap"></span>
                </a>
              </h6>

              <a class="landingbtn" href="#portfolio">
                <p> See my work </p>
            </a>
        </div>
    </header>

    <section id="about" class="about">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="prolife-img" data-aos="fade-right" data-aos-delay="200">
                <img src="images/profile(1).png" alt="avatar image">
            </div>
            <div class="about-details" data-aos="fade-left" data-aos-delay="400">
                <div class="about-heading">
                    <h1>About</h1>
                </div>
                <p>
                    A confident individual offering skills in a range of areas, 
                    from anlytical and formulation chemistry to, web development, 
                    backend, hospitality and sales. 

                    Self-taught full stack developer, offering skills in web-design, 
                    python, data science and analysis. 
                </p>
                <div class="social-media">
                    <ul class="nav-list">
                        <li>
                            <a href="#" class="icon-link">
                                <i class="fab fa-linkedin"></i>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#" class="icon-link">
                                <i class="fab fa-github"></i>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#" class="icon-link">
                                <i class="fab fa-soundcloud"></i>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>

    <section class="services" id="services">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="section-heading">
                <h1 data-aos="zoom-in" data-aos-delay="100">Services</h1>
                <h6 data-aos="zoom-in" data-aos-delay="100">What I Can Do For You</h6>
            </div>
            <div class="my-skills">
                <div class="skill" data-aos="fade-left" data-aos-delay="300">
                    <div class="icon-container">
                        <i class="fas fa-code"></i>
                    </div>
                    <h1>Design & Development</h1>
                    <p>
                        Good web design is more thanjust pixelated information. 
                        It should be seamless, it should be invisible. 
                        In my hands, every project is bespoke and tailored to your specific needs and requirements.
                        In a few short months I have developed and deployed a number of websites, find our more in my portfolio.
                        
                    </p>
                </div>
                <div class="skill" data-aos="fade-in" data-aos-delay="150">
                    <div class="icon-container">
                        <i class="fa fa-cogs"></i>
                    </div>
                    <h1>Design & Deployment</h1>
                    <p>
                        Over the last few months I have devloped my python skills, developing a number of applications,
                        and sucessfully depolying a few. I am drawn to data analysis and visulation, data can truly be beautiful. 
                        Although not an expert, far from it, I am working everyday to expand my skillset.
                        What I have developed so far, in a short period of time, can show what I can do.
                    </p>
                </div>
                <div class="skill" data-aos="fade-right" data-aos-delay="300">
                    <div class="icon-container">  
                        <i class="fa fa-dashboard"></i>
                    </div>
                    <h1>Versitility</h1>
                    <p>
                        I take pride in having a versitile skill-set, from sales,  to business, to programming, to life sciences, to music and creative design. 
                        Those 'soft-skils', and my exposiure to a range of feilds and industries, means that I'm sure there's some way I can be of service.
                        These are more words, included to make this look right. 
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>


    <section class="portfolio" id="portfolio">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="section-heading" data-aos="zoom-in" data-aos-delay="100">
                <h1 data-aos="fade-right" data-aos-delay="150">Portfolio</h1>
                <h6 data-aos="fade-left" data-aos-delay="150">Veiw Recent Projects</h6>
            </div>
            </div>

            <div class="row" data-aos="fade-down" data-aos-delay="200"> 

                <!-- Portfolio Item 1 | AB Removals -->
                <div class="column">
                    <div class="portfolio-container">
                        <div class="item" id="1">
                            <img src="/images/abremovals.png" style="width:100%"  alt="">
                            <div class="text">
                                <h3>PROJECT 1</h4>
                                    <p>Short Description</p>
                                </div>
                                <div class="button">Learn More</div>
                            </div>
                    </div>

                    <!-- Portfolio Item 2 | Resume -->
                    <div class="portfolio-container">
                        <div class="item" id="2">
                            <img src="/images/resume.png" style="width:100%" alt="">
                            <div class="text">
                                <h3>PROJECT 2</h4>
                                    <p>Short Description</p>
                                </div>
                                <div class="button">Learn More</div>
                            </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

            
            <!-- Portfolio Item 3 | Resume -->
            <div class="column">
                <div class="portfolio-container">
                    <div class="item" id="3">
                        <img src="/images/portfolio.png" style="width:100%" alt="">
                        <div class="text">
                            <h3>PROJECT 3</h4>
                                <p>Short Description</p>
                            </div>
                            <div class="button">Learn More</div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <!-- Portfolio Item 4 | Data Projects -->
                    <div class="portfolio-container">
                        <div class="item" id="4">
                            <img src="/images/covid.png" style="width:100%" alt="">
                            <div class="text">
                                <h3>PROJECT 4</h4>
                                    <p>Short Description</p>
                                </div>
                                <div class="button">Learn More</div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
            </div>

            

            <!-- Portfolio Item 5 | Colour Detection -->
            <div class="column">
                <div class="portfolio-container">
                    <div class="item" id="5">
                        <img src="/images/testimage.gif" style="width:100%" alt="">
                        <div class="text">
                            <h3>PROJECT 5</h4>
                                <p>Short Description</p>
                            </div>
                            <div class="button">Learn More</div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <!-- Portfolio Item 6 | Face Detection -->
                    <div class="portfolio-container">
                    <div class="item" id="6">
                        <img src="/images/testgiftwo.gif" alt="">
                        <div class="text">
                            <h3>PROJECT 6</h4>
                                <p>Short Description</p>
                            </div>
                            <div class="button">Learn More</div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
            </div>

                        <!-- Portfolio Item 7 | Colour Detection -->
                        <div class="column">
                            <div class="portfolio-container">
                                <div class="item" id="7">
                                    <img src="/images/testimage.gif" style="width:100%" alt="">
                                    <div class="text">
                                        <h3>PROJECT 7</h4>
                                            <p>Short Description</p>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="button">Learn More</div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <!-- Portfolio Item 8 | Colour Detection -->
                                <div class="portfolio-container">
                                <div class="item" id="8">
                                    <img src="/images/testimage.gif" style="width:100%" alt="">
                                    <div class="text">
                                        <h3>PROJECT 8</h4>
                                            <p>Short Description</p>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="button">Learn More</div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                        </div>
            

            <!-- Modal -->
            <div id="preview" class="modal">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <span class="close">&times;</span>
                    <div id="details">
                        <h3 id="title"></h3>
                        <p id="info">SOME TEXT</p>
                        <div class="button" id="live">View</div>
                        <i class="fab fa-github-square" id="github"></i>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- Item End -->            

            

    </section>

    <section class="experience" id="experience">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="section-heading">
                <h1 data-aos="fade-left" data-aos-delay="150">Work Experience</h1>
                <h6 data-aos="fade-right" data-aos-delay="150">Previous Roles</h6>
            </div>
            <div class="timeline" data-aos="fade-down" data-aos-delay="200">
                <ul>
                    <li class="date" data-date="Oct 2018 - Dec 2019">
                        <h1>Mettler Toledo | Sales Coordinator</h1>
                        <p>
                            The key aim of this role was to sell or introduce new corporate products or services to
                            established clients, along with prospecting for new business, the generation and qualification of sales leads.

                            Management of project execution actions and overall coordination between Internal and Outside Sales departments,
                            along with key stakeholders both inside, and beyond the business.
                        </p>
                    </li>
                    <li class="date" data-date="Mar 2018 - Jan 2019">
                        <h1>Vape.ABox | Flavourist - Lead Chemist</h1>
                        <p>
                            Set up and maintenance of the analytical laboratory on site, along with product procurement.
                            Demonstration of creation leadership potential through commercial projects & their execution.
                            Creation of new flavors and re-formulation of current flavours, with regards to specific technologies and delivery systems.
                        </p>
                    </li>
                    <li class="date" data-date="Mar 2018 - Jan 2019">
                        <h1>3M | QC Inhilations Chemist</h1>
                        <p>
                            Testing of pharmaceutical products for batch release, stability and complaints in line with departmental
                            and site procedures across a number of departments.
                            Completion of work and documentation to standards of compliance designated by external regulatory 
                            bodies and internal Company procedures.

                        </p>
                    </li>
                    <h2>Further information regarding my work experience can be found in my Resume</h2>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>

    <section class="contact" id="contact">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="section-heading">
                <h1 data-aos="fade-right" data-aos-delay="150">Contact</h1>
                <h6 data-aos="fade-left" data-aos-delay="150">Contact Me</h6>
            </div>
            <form actions="" data-aos="fade-up" data-aos-delay="200">
                <label for="name">Name:</label>
                <input type="text" id="name" name="name" placeholder="Enter Your Name..." required>

                <label for="name">Email:</label>
                <input type="email" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Enter Your E-mail..." required>

                <label for="number">Contact Number:</label>
                <input type="number" id="number" name="number" placeholder="Enter Your Contact Number...">
                
                <label for="message">Message:</label>
                <textarea name="subject" id="subject" cols="10" rows="10" placeholder="Enter Your Messgage..."></textarea>
                <input type="submit" value="Subit">


            </form>
        </div>
    </section>

    <footer class="copyright">
        <div class="up" id="up">
                    <i class="fas fa fa-chevron-up"></i>
        </div>
        <p>&copy; 2020 Karanvir S. Ghattoraya</p>
    </footer>


        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/aos@next/dist/aos.js"></script>






</body>
```

Comment: You should describe what you did and why - otherwise it's hard to find the changes and on top of that people cannot learn what they did wrong.

Comment: Please avoid posting profanity, as it is noticed and could subject you to flags and moderator action.